# JQuery focus on tab pressed

Tags: focus

Hi I am trying to make an input field focused when tab is pressed on another input field, but it's not working, anyone can tell me why?

Here is the code I'm using:

http://jsfiddle.net/kk4GN/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `event.preventDefault();`

**update** — http://jsfiddle.net/kk4GN/7/

Comment: there is an important problem here though, I cannot type in the first text box when I use event.preventDefault(), what's the workaround? I need to keep the functionality for people to write in the input boxes.

Comment: I guess I didn't really test it, I had just placed the `event.preventDefault();` statement in the wrong place